# Call a method when another method is called?

Tags: java

Now I am very aware that you can simply do the following:

```
public static void methodA() {
   doSomeOtherStuffHere();
   methodB(); 
}

public static void methodB() {
    doStuffHere();
}
```

But in my scenario, I cannot change the code of method A ( I cannot add the `methodB();` ). So is there any way I can detect when `method A` is called (and then execute `method B` when it is)?

Comment: what's the reason behind not knowing when methodA() is called? I mean, if you are the caller of methodA(), why not just put methodB() call just after the first call? I may be missing something in your context thou

Comment: Lol you did not miss anything in the context. In my case, and my apologies for not being more clear about this, the only code I can change is methodB() and any other classes I make myself. So the class calling the methodA cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Java,  you can do this by creating a subclass of the Class (Which owns methodA) and override the method methodA. Write your own Implementation and use the subclass method where ever you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Aspect Oriented Programming (https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) to create aspect which will be executed before `YourClass.methodB()`

Answer (score 0):

in you code you have "doSomeOtherStuff()" method. You could place methodB within it. Here is an example:

```
public class App{

      public static boolean isCalled = true;

       public static void main( String[] args ){

              starterMethod();

       }

       public static void methodB() {
             System.out.println("Method B started");
       }

       public static void starterMethod() {
             methodB();
         }

      }
```

In you example you can call "doOtherStuffHere". You could call methodB within doOtherStuffHere and that method could contain a call to methodB.